# AXIOS POST request is not sent and the function stops working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, axios

I have a login function that is supposed to trigger an AXIOS POST request and get the response and save it in AsyncStorage (I am in React Native). Same code works on React however here I am not able to run it. To debug it, I placed several alert functions. The login function does not go further than the "second call"

I am not able to understand (now for days) why the rest of the function is not triggered, and if it is, no error is apparent.

Here is my function:

```
export const login = (email, password) => async(dispatch) => {
    try {
        dispatch({ type: USER_LOGIN_REQUEST });

        alert('first call')
    
        const config = {
            headers: {
                "Content-type": "application/json"
            }
        }

        alert('second call')

        const { data } = await axios.post("url/login", {email, password}, config)
        alert('third call')


        dispatch({type: USER_LOGIN_SUCCESS, payload:data});
        alert('fourth call')

     
        alert(JSON.stringify(data) + `hello`)
        await AsyncStorage.setItem("userInfo", JSON.stringify(data))
        alert('final call')
        alert(userInfo)

        
    } catch (error) {
        dispatch({
            type: USER_LOGIN_FAIL,
            payload: 
                error.response && error.response.data.message
                    ? error.response.data.message 
                    : error.message,
        })

        alert("This login attempt is unsuccessful");
        alert(error)
        
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you configure a baseUrl for your axios client? Try for example calling a full url (with http://) in `axios.post("url/login"...`
You could also add a `try/catch` to see more details about the error : 

```try {
        const { data } = await axios.post("url/login", {email, password}, config)
} catch(e) {
  console.log('Something went wront, see?', e)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you could confirm that the axios request is indeed sent, then something must be wrong with your axios request (or the server receiving this request).

Did you check whether the request throws an error and you `catch` block is executed? (For example because of some CORS issues)

If the `catch` block is not executed then the promise returned by the axios request did not resolve/reject yet. The reason for this could be a server-side issue - is something keeping your server from responding? Are you calling the server with the correct URI?

In your code example you specify the path `url/login`; this can work as a valid URI on the web (because axios appends this relative path to your current `window.location.pathname`), however, mobile apps have no concept of a `domain` the way web-apps have it. So the same request will fail in react native. Instead, specify the full path (`{protocol}://{domain}/{path}`) of your server and see if that works.

Comment: Thanks - did all this and yes my endpoint is in fact in correct format. I am sending the answer now

Answer (score 0):

The way to solve this (at least for me) turned out to downgrade from React Native 0.66 to 0.64. I was always getting a warning with Expo app saying that Expo SDK would better work with 0.64.

When I had no other recourse to take, I downgraded to 0.64, did not change the code and the requests and the axios posts are being returned/executed now.

In case anyone encounters this kind of a problem, please take note of version errors that do not reveal themselves as I had been stuck at this for 4 days now.

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).